# How to get the value of a function from a ASP.NET web page with JS as href link using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium-webdriver, hyperlink

I'm trying to use the browser automation library [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/javascript/index.html) with a Chrome Driver to get the download `.asp` file which is received after clicking the link.

The Website hosts .aspx files. This is how I get the web page:

```
//Inside a Javascript function: 
let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
await driver.get("https://xxx.xxx.xx.xx/users/Customer.aspx");
```

This page contains the following element:

```
<a id="ctl00_main_bttnExportRegister" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$main$bttnExportRegister','')">Export Register</a>
```

When this element is clicked, a `downloaded.asp` file is prompted to download. The `downloaded.asp` file contains pure HTML.

**I don't need to download the file I just want to access the html content that the `downloaded.asp` provides. How can I achieve this?**

Thank you for your help.